# How to display specific value from SQL in a dropdown depending on another condition

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need some help for a problem that I have been stuck with for a while.

I have a list with ads showing vehicles of different categories - cars, motorcycles, trucks, boats etc. I have a dropdown that should work as a filter. Depending on what vehicles are in the list, the dropdown values should be equal to the category of the vehicle.

For example, if in the list there are 3 cars: Audi, BMW and Porsche and 2 boats: Cranchi and Azimut, the dropdown should show 5 values: Audi, BMW, Porsche, Cranchi, Azimut.

However, for the example above i only manage to show in the dropdown all car and boat makes from the DB, but not only the relevant to the list entries.

Here is my code, any ideas will be appreciated:

```
<option value="">Please Select</option>
                        <?php
                         if($all=='ALL')
                            {
                        foreach($arrVehicleType as $arrVehicleTypes){


                        $qry_makes_all  = "SELECT * FROM ".$tblprefix."makes WHERE  status ='1' AND type = '".$arrVehicleTypes."' ORDER BY title ASC";
                        $rs_makes_all   = $db->Execute($qry_makes_all);
                         while(!$rs_makes_all->EOF){

                             $sql_query_all_all     = "SELECT type FROM ".$tblprefix."vehicles WHERE user_dealer_id = '".$DealeId."' AND  make='".$rs_makes_all->fields['id']."' AND user_dealer_type = 2   AND completed_status = 1 AND  status = 1 ";     
                             $rs_results_all_all    = $db -> Execute($sql_query_all_all);
                             $TYPE = $rs_results_all_all -> fields['type'];
?>


                <option value="<?php echo $rs_makes_all->fields['id'];?>,<?php echo $rs_makes_all->fields['title']." ($vehicletext)";?>
                </option>
                <?php $rs_makes_all->MoveNext();  } }} else {
                  while(!$rs_makes->EOF){?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $rs_makes->fields['id'];?>,,<?php echo $arrVehicleType[0];?>">
                        <?php echo $rs_makes->fields['title'];?>
                        </option>

                        <?php 

                        $rs_makes->MoveNext(); } } ?>
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT in Mysql.

```
$qry_makes_all  = "SELECT DISTINCT /* list column names */ FROM ".$tblprefix."makes WHERE  status ='1' AND type = '".$arrVehicleTypes."' ORDER BY title ASC";
```

This will select all the distinct values from your table.